# О пунктуации (нужна ли запятая)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы

Нужно ли ставить запятую перед "что" в предложении: "Довожу до Вашего сведения, что детали, закупленные в прошлом месяце, не дошли"?

Answer (score 1):

Лучше сказать так: **Довожу до Вашего сведения, что детали, закупленные в прошлом месяце, доставлены не были.**

Или: Довожу до Вашего сведения, что закупленные в прошлом месяце детали доставлены не были.

Запятая ставится перед союзом ЧТО в сложноподчиненном предложении, также **обособляется причастный оборот** *закупленные в прошлом месяце*, если он стоит **после определяемого слова** *детали*.